# Testing if a projection is uniform over an F# sequence

Tags: f#

I want to check if a projection over a sequence has a uniform value in F#.

Here's what I have:

```ml
module Seq = 

  let isUniformBy (f) (xs : seq<_>) = 
    let l = 
      xs
      |> Seq.map f
      |> Seq.distinct
      |> Seq.truncate 2
      |> Seq.length
    
    l < 2

  let isUniform xs = isUniformBy id xs

printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 2; 3 ] // false
printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 1; 1 ] // true
printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy id [ ] // true
printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 1 ] // true
printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 1; 2 ] // false
printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 2 ] // false
printfn "%b" <| Seq.isUniformBy (fun x -> x % 2) [ 2; 4; 6; 8 ] // true
```

I was wondering if there was a built-in function for this already?
And if not, what is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can reduce the problem to comparing adjacent elements - because for uniformity, we can't have any element that's not the same as one preceding it.

This means we only need to check if there's one such pair - we only need to enumerate the sequence until we find the pair.

```
let isUniform xs = 
    xs
    |> Seq.pairwise
    |> Seq.exists (fun (a, b) -> a <> b)
    |> not

let isUniformBy (f) (lst : seq<_>) = 
    lst |> Seq.map f |> isUniform
```

The base method is `isUniform`, so we can pass a projected sequence to it from `isUniformBy`, avoiding a pass through `id`. Additionally, we only use O(1) space.

**Tests**

```
assert( Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 2; 3 ] = false)
assert( Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 1; 1 ] = true)
assert( Seq.isUniformBy id [ ] = true)
assert( Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 1 ] = true)
assert( Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 1; 2 ] = false)
assert( Seq.isUniformBy id [ 1; 2 ] = false)
assert( Seq.isUniformBy (fun x -> x % 2) [ 2; 4; 6; 8 ] = true)
```

Comment: I like this approach, but I think you actually want `isUniform` to be `Seq.forall (fun (a, b) -> a = b)`, or add `|> not` at the end of the function.

Comment: @brianberns Forgot about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the first two calls using `Seq.distinctBy` ([link](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#distinctBy)), and then simplify slightly more via `Seq.tryExactlyOne` ([link](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-seqmodule.html#tryExactlyOne)), although it will then report `false` for an empty sequence:

```
let isUniformBy f xs =
    xs
        |> Seq.distinctBy f
        |> Seq.tryExactlyOne
        |> Option.isSome
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is not about the best (that is, most readable, and efficient), but the shortest way, I'd follow OP's approach and optimize it a bit:

```
module Seq =
    let isUniformBy f x = Seq.groupBy f x |> Seq.length < 2
    // val isUniformBy : f:('a -> 'b) -> x:seq<'a> -> bool when 'b : equality

[ id, [ 1; 2; 3 ] // false
  id, [ 1; 1; 1 ] // true
  id, [ ]         // true
  id, [ 1; 1 ]    // true
  id, [ 1; 1; 2 ] // false
  id, [ 1; 2 ]    // false
  (fun x -> x % 2), [ 2; 4; 6; 8 ]] // true
|> Seq.iter ((<||) Seq.isUniformBy >> printfn "%b")
```